# How to add input from form to url?

Tags: php, api

I'm trying to use ip lookup api but im facing issues while trying to add the input i.e. IP in the api URL, somebody please guide me on the solution.Appreciate for all your help!!

```
<?php 
  include 'includes/header.php';
?>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h1 style="font-weight:600;">IP LOOKUP</h1>
      <form action="ip_lookup.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="IP" placeholder="Enter IP">
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['IP'])){
      $got = $_POST['IP'];
    }
  }
  $ip_look = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.domaintools.com/v1/$got/whois/'));
  var_dump($ip_look);
?>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Single-quoted strings don't interpolate variables, double-quoted strings do: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String interpolation is restricted with single quotes `'`.
Several options to fix:

- Use double quotes `"`

  ```
  "https://api.domaintools.com/v1/$got/whois/"
  ```
- Concatenate

  ```
  "https://api.domaintools.com/v1/" . $got . "/whois/"
  ```
- Using `sprintf()`

  ```
  sprintf("https://api.domaintools.com/v1/%s/whois/", $got);
  ```

See https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Getting this:  Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.domaintools.com/v1/domain/whois/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in D:\xampp\htdocs\Show My IP\ip_lookup.php on line 18
NULL

Comment: @Cybil Looks like that website isn't letting you do that request. Perhaps you need an API key or something like that?